# Linux systemd: remove slice

Tags: linux, systemd

Out of curiosity, is there any way to remove a systemd slice that you've created? I'm running on Fedora 28 with systemd-238-9 and kernel 4.17.12-200.fc28.x86_64 .

I performed:

```
systemd-run --unit=toptest --slice=test top -b
```

And after the `top` had exited, I can see my slice:

```
systemctl -t slice --all
```

But I can't remove it. I have tried

```
systemctl stop test.slice
systemctl kill test.slice
systemctl unload test.slice
```

(the latter gives an "unknown operation"), but still my slice lives in that list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On my FC28 system the test slice disappears after the `systemctl stop test.slice` command.
Trying the kill afterwards gives this result:

```
systemctl kill  test.slice
Failed to kill unit test.slice: Unit test.slice not loaded.
```